# Cartoon/anime that featured a huge orange see-through beast that was controlled by the protagonist

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

As the title mentioned, it featured who I think is the protagonist being able to take command of a huge 'monster' or 'robot' (unsure of what type of thing it was that, if I recall correctly, was orange and transparent/see-through, seemingly made of energy. Might have had designs along its body of a different colour, white perhaps, but my memory is very hazy.

I can't be sure, but perhaps other characters could also take command of avatars of their own, they were all super huge, the size of small buildings I think. I don't even remember what shape this 'monster' would have had, whether it was humanoid or resembled an animal or something. This has haunted my memory for years.

Comment: Was this an American cartoon? Was it broadcasted on the Cartoon Network, or another channel?

Comment: could it be Naruto?

Comment: @Baku Nine-tailed fox!

Comment: @DeutschPirate it's hard to remember, I would imagine it was broadcast on Cartoon Network, but can't be sure. It also seemed contemporary, not like a show from the 90s or earlier. Baku, definitely not Naruto, I know of that show, but a good suggestion anyway. Thank you all. I will continue digging at my brain to try to remember more details.

Answer (score 5):

## Tye Longshadow

On [*Young Justice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Justice_(TV_series)) season 2 (2012-2013), [Tye Longshadow](http://youngjustice.wikia.com/wiki/Tye_Longshadow) controls a giant transparent orange astral form that he projects around his physical body:

[image: Tye Longshadow and his astral form]

This character is the equivalent of the [*Super Friends*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Friends) hero [Apache Chief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Chief).

No other characters on *Young Justice* show this ability, and the astral body has no distinctive markings in a different colour, so this isn't a perfect match for the description you gave.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I have the impression that in the show I'm thinking of, every character had some avatar like the one I described (albeit with different features).

Answer (score 1):

I vaguely remember my daughter watching something that sounded like a possibility. It's was called [Ushio to Tora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushio_and_Tora).

Comment: Can you give us some more information as to why you think this is the right answer?

Comment: Checked it out, it's not what I'm thinking about but thanks for the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## Larfleeze (Orange Lantern Corps)

In [*Green Lantern: The Animated Series*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Lantern:_The_Animated_Series) (2012-2013) episode 1x23 (["Larfleeze"](http://gltas.wikia.com/wiki/Larfleeze_(episode))), the alien known as Larfleeze channels the power of avarice (greed and envy) to create orange energy effigies of himself and his victims.

Hal Jordan, a human member of the Green Lantern Corps, briefly wields the orange power.

Although Larfleeze is human-sized, his energy constructs can be much larger:

[image: A giant effigy of Larfleeze, holding Hal Jordan in his left hand.]

<sup>*— A giant effigy of Larfleeze captures Hal Jordan.*</sup>

The [Orange Lantern Corps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larfleeze#Orange_Lantern_Corps) (of which Larfleeze is usually the sole member) has a logo (circular, with radial lines) that appears on their uniforms and on their constructs:

[image: Lorfleeze]

<sup>*— Orange Lantern Corps logo on the shoulder of Larfleeze.*</sup>

[image: Glomulus effigy]

<sup>*— Logo on the chest of an orange energy construct.*</sup>

Comment: Great suggestion, but not what I was thinking about.